# Send specific rsyslog facility to remote server and not local

Tags: syslog

I have a rsyslog facility (local1) that is used by one application only, and I would like to send the logs from that to a remote server but *not* to the local machine. I've managed to find the info in the rsyslog docs to send it to a remote server, so now I have this:

```
local1.*                       @logserver:514
```

But what I didn't realize (until /var filled up...) is that these messages were also going into /var/log/messages. How do I get them to only get sent to the remote server? I'm not bothered about losing a few messages, they're for analysis rather than debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Many default rsyslog configs already have an example of excluding facilities:

```
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          /var/log/syslog
```

The second line will log everything except `auth.*` and `authpriv.*`.

Comment: OK, I think I see. So I want to do something like:

local1.*                       -/var/log/messages

I'll give that a try, thanks.

Comment: You picked the wrong line; the exclusion is in `<facility>.none`.